# Passing Form Values into a file or not

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this is a silly question, I am still pretty new to PHP/MySQL and I am wondering which structure is more secure(if possible) and a smarter way to handle posting form data..

ie.

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="somefolder/somefile.php">
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you're asking these sorts of questions, you really should be using [a framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) to better structure your application.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really change anything.

If you can get into location A and from that location to location B in the system and both locations have the same kind of protection then it doesn't really matter.

What matters is, for example, that you validate all inputs.

Comment: Don't merely hash passwords. This is just one of many things [you should never do in PHP](http://biasedphp.com/php-commandments).

Comment: True, but I'm talking about hashing, not pure encryption. Anyway It's a little too specific to mention anyway.